# open() system call working differently

Tags: c

#### Program 1

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int fd1, fd2;
   fd1 = open("dup1.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT| S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
   printf("\nOriginal fd = %d", fd1);
   if(fd1 == -1){
     printf("\nFATAL Error\n");
     exit(1);
   }
}
```

#### Program 2

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int fd1, fd2;
   fd1 = open("dup1.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
   printf("\nOriginal fd = %d", fd1);
   if(fd1 == -1){
     printf("\nFATAL Error\n");
     exit(1);
   }
}
```

The program1 returns -1 for fd, if the file already exists (works fine when it doesn't), but the program2 below the first one works fine. The difference is placement of option flags.

Comment: You may want to mention the platform these are both tested on.

Answer (score 4):

On my machine, `S_IWRITE` has the same value as `O_EXCL`. The program:

```
int main() { 
    printf("%x %x\n", S_IREAD, S_IWRITE);
    printf("%x\n", O_EXCL);

    return 0; 
}
```

gives:

```
100 80
80
```

So I **guess**, specifying the flag `S_IWRITE` together with `O_CREAT` now has the same effect as `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`, which causes `open` to fail if the file already exists.

However, I think you should invoke the system calls with the proper use of their arguments.

Comment: Would octal be 'better' than hex for this? The `S_IWRITE` would be more recognizable that way.

Answer (score 2):

The `open` system call may be called with either 2 or 3 arguments.

These two calls:

```
fd1 = open("dup1.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT| S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
```

and

```
fd1 = open("dup1.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
```

are quite different; the first passes a second argument equal to `O_RDWR | O_CREAT| S_IREAD | S_IWRITE`, and the second passes a second argument equal to `O_RDWR | O_CREAT` and a third argument equal to `S_IREAD | S_IWRITE`.

The second argument should always be a bitwise "or" of one or more flags whose names start with `O_`.

If and only if the second argument includes the `O_CREAT` flag, you need to pass a second argument, which should be either a bitwise "or" of one or more flags whose names start with `S_`, or an octal number such as `0640` specifying permissions.

Your first call is incorrect; you shouldn't pass `S_*` flags in the second argument, and if the second argument includes `O_CREAT`, you need a third argument.

This ability to pass either two or three arguments is a bit odd. The Linux man page documents `open` like this:

```
 int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
 int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

which is arguably incorrect (C doesn't have function overloading like that). POSIX describes it like this:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

making it a *variadic* function, similar to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `O_CREAT`, [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) takes three arguments and the third argument is the permissions on the file to be created:

```
fd1 = open("dup1.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
```

The permissions (`S_I*` flags) are never specified in the options (second) argument (which uses `O_*` flags) or vice versa.  Theoretically the symbolic names are more portable than the octal literals, but IMNSHO octal literals are easier to interpret. You can use whatever permissions you like, but unless you're creating executable programs, you probably should not be setting the `x` bit for anyone, and for security reasons, you should consider not granting group or public write access (allowing group and public read access to be overridden by [`umask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) as the user sees fit.  Classically (in the days of yore when security was less of a concern), permissions were habitually 0666 by default for files.